# Change styling of div when a click out of the div is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 8 divs in Bootstrap and I can change the styling of a div when I click on it with the following code;

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".continue--btn").hide();

    if ($('.generator--templates').click(function(){
  $('.continue--btn').show();
  $(this).css("background", "#03A9F3");
  $(this).find('.generator--templates__description, .generator--templates__purpose').css("color", "#fff");
})
);
```

This also shows a button to continue.

However, the next thing I want to do is when I click anywhere but the div, div gets his default styling and that the button will disappear again.

I can not wrap my head around this.

I've tried this:

```
var templates = document.getElementsByClassName('.generator--templates');

window.onclick = function(event){
  if (event.target == templates){
        templates.style.background = "#fff";
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make your question clear and go straight to the main point, I can't understand what you want and I can't help you. As I understand, you may try this `$(document).click(function(){ $('#divid').addClass("redColor") });`

Comment: Have you tried with the `body` tag instead ?

Comment: Maybe this will help you [codepen](https://codepen.io/bassta/pen/ndfDq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly note that your syntax is incorrect in that you have placed a `click()` handler in an `if` statement.

Secondly, `templates` will be a collection of elements returned from `getElementsByClassName`. Therefore comparing it to the Element in `event.target` is never going to match.

To fix the issue put a click handler on the `document` and check the class of the target element, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.generator--templates').click(function() {
    $('.continue--btn').show();
    $(this).find('.generator--templates__description, .generator--templates__purpose').addBack().addClass('active');
  })

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var $target = $(this);
    if ($target.is('.generator--templates') || $target.closest('.generator--templates').length) {
      $('.continue--btn').hide();
      $('.generator--templates').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.continue--btn { 
  display: none;
}

.generator--templates.active,
.generator--templates__description.active,
.generator--templates__purpose.active {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Note the use of CSS here instead of `css()` which should be avoided where possible, as it ties the JS logic too closely to the UI.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation; could you explain why it is incorrect to place a click() handler in an if statement?

Comment: The `click()` statement returns a jQuery object, so will always equate to `true`, therefore it's pointless code.

Comment: may be `$target.hasClass('generator--templates')`  instead of `$target.is('.generator--templates')` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```js
$(".continue--btn").hide();
$('.generator--templates').click(function() {
  // reset the sibling elements
  $(this).siblings('.generator--templates').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).find('.continue--btn').hide();
    $(el).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
    $(el).find('.generator--templates__description, .generator--templates__purpose').css("color", "transparent");
  });
  // apply changes to clicked item
  $(this).find('.continue--btn').show();
  $(this).css("background", "#03A9F3");
  $(this).find('.generator--templates__description, .generator--templates__purpose').css("color", "#fff");
});
$('.body').click(function(e) { // change '.body' to 'body' for your code
  var $target = jQuery(e.target);
  if ($target.hasClass('generator--templates') ||
    $target.closest('.generator--templates').length > 0) {
    // Clicked on a box
  } else { // Clicked elsewhere
    $('.generator--templates').each(function(i, el) {
      $(el).find('.continue--btn').hide();
      $(el).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)');
      $(el).find('.generator--templates__description, .generator--templates__purpose').css("color", "transparent");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.body {
  /* added just for display */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px
}

.generator--templates {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="body">
  <div class="container-element">
    <div class="generator--templates one">
      <button class="continue--btn">Continue</button>
    </div>
    <div class="generator--templates two">
      <button class="continue--btn">Continue</button>
    </div>
    <div class="generator--templates three">
      <button class="continue--btn">Continue</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```